# Creating histogram from SQL

Tags: sql, analytics, vertica

I want to build a histogram from SQL result (Vertica).
I used WIDTH_BUCKET to do this.

Basically, the way I approach is to get timestamp of event_X and event_Y where target value matches under each event. Then taking a diff of timestamp of each event.

```
select _time, WIDTH_BUCKET(_time, 600, 86400, 100) as histogram 
    from(        
    select (a.ts - b.ts) as _time
FROM table.e a, table.e b
WHERE a.server_date between current_date - 60 and current_date -1 
AND a.event_name = 'event_X'
AND b.event_name = 'event_Y'
and ((a.ts - b.ts) > INTERVAL '5 minutes' and (a.ts - b.ts) < INTERVAL '24 hours')
AND a.target = b.target
)x
group by 1
order by 1 ASC
```

However, this returns following error.

```
ERROR: Function WIDTH_BUCKET(interval(in seconds), int, int, int) does not exist, or permission is denied for WIDTH_BUCKET(interval(in seconds), int, int, int)
```

a.ts-b.ts is INTERVAL data type of timestamp because ts is time data type.
I don't know why I'm getting this error..

If someone can clarify what's wrong on my SQL, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just to be certain, you do have permission, correct?

Comment: Yes. I ran a different query with WIDTH_BUCKET and it worked. That did not have INTERVAL value. Just has plain numeric value. This specific query returns the error above.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `_time` going to be different for different records in this table? The buckets can't have different intervals per record, right?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Use TIMESTAMPDIFF instead of (a.ts - b.ts)

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(mi, b.ts, a.ts) >  10
```

Documentation: 
https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/TIMESTAMPDIFF.htm